# can we disable cursor on alertbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable cursor pointer when my alert box will appear. How can I do that with the help of JavaScript?

```
<script>
    function showalertbox(){
        alert('dfsdfdfs');  
        document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
     }
     showalertbox();
</script>
```

Comment: i dont think this is possible.. but you might make it using a lightbox and styling the cursor to be disabled using css

Comment: You can hide the cursor on your body but you can not control to the alert cursor. Your code work for DOM only

Comment: create your own custom alert box and use cursor property

Comment: @ShrikanthBuds Kabali  thanks you for your reply..
but i have seen in one website that it hides the cursor even on alert box.
i wish i could share the link but that link is having virus so i am not sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

The alert and confirm boxes are notoriously uncustomizable (in other words, no, you can't do that).  This is because they are hard-wired into the browser code, and therefore not part of the DOM.  If you want to customize your alert boxes, consider using one of the many plugins for dialog boxes that are available.  However, if you do that, you will create complications due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, especially if you are wanting to emulate the confirm box.  You'll need to work out how to handle async callbacks.